# Extjs on load Sort

Tags: extjs, grid, visualforce, extjs3

Folks,

I am developing a Visualforce page with ExtJS Grid in it.

Is there any method to sort the specific grid column to ASC or DESC?

I am using ExtJS 3.2.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

In order to sort the grid, it will have options in the column headers to allow a user to sort. If you want to do it programatically I believe you need to sort the `'store'` which the grid is bound to.

You can then specify a sort config on the store (if you want default sorting on initial load) e.g.

```
sortInfo: {
    field: 'fieldName',
    direction: 'ASC' // or 'DESC' (case sensitive for local sorting)
}
```

other that the sort info config on the store, you can explicitely call the 'sort' method on the store passing through a fieldname and direction e.g.

```
theStore.sort({
   field    : 'salary',
   direction: 'DESC'
});
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate this more.
I ma new to this Extjs.

Comment: On what aspect would you like some elaboration? can you describe your specific issue in some more detail (e.g. what you want to happen, how your code looks at the moment, what you've tried etc?)